# Получение значений из кастомного многомерного массива

Tags: php

Есть массив, как мне получать значения sender_name, timestamp_ms, link

```
array(6) { 
["participants"]=> array(9) { 
    [0]=> array(1) { ["name"]=> string(33) "ÐÐ»ÑÑ Ð¨Ð¾ÑÑ" } 
    [1]=> array(1) { ["name"]=> string(49) "ÐÐ¸ÑÐ¸Ð»Ð» ÐÑÑÐ½Ð¸Ñ" } 
    [2]=> array(1) { ["name"]=> string(61) "ÐÐ°ÐºÑÐ¸Ð¼ ÐÑÐ±Ð¸ÑÐµÐ»ÐµÐ²" } 
    [3]=> array(1) { ["name"]=> string(37) "ÐÐ°ÐºÑÐ¸Ð¼ ÐÑÑ" } 
    [4]=> array(1) { ["name"]=> string(65) "ÐÐ»ÐµÐºÑÐµÐ¹ Ð Ð°Ð¼ÐµÐ½ÑÐºÐ¸Ð¹" } 
    [5]=> array(1) { ["name"]=> string(49) "ÐÐ°ÑÑÑ ÐÐ²Ð°Ð½Ð¾Ð²Ð°" } 
    [6]=> array(1) { ["name"]=> string(49) "ÐÐ³Ð¾ÑÑ ÐÐ»Ð°Ð´ÐºÐ¸Ñ" } 
    [7]=> array(1) { ["name"]=> string(14) "ÐÐ³Ð¾ÑÑ ÐÐ»Ð°Ð´ÐºÐ¸Ñ" } 
    [8]=> array(1) { ["name"]=> string(61) "ÐÐ½Ð´ÑÐµÐ¹ Ð¡Ð¾Ð»Ð¾Ð¼Ð¾Ð½Ð¾Ð²" } 
} 
        ["messages"]=> array(2) { 
            [0]=> array(5) { 
                ["sender_name"]=> string(65) "ÐÐ»ÐµÐºÑÐµÐ¹ Ð Ð°Ð¼ÐµÐ½ÑÐºÐ¸Ð¹" 
                ["timestamp_ms"]=> int(1543941856123) 
                ["content"]=> string(59) "https://www.facebook.com/716628253/posts/10157110751043254/" 
                ["share"]=> array(1) { 
                    ["link"]=> string(58) "https://www.facebook.com/shipachev/posts/10157110751043254" 
                } 
                ["type"]=> string(5) "Share" 
            } 
            [1]=> array(5) { 
                ["sender_name"]=> string(61) "ÐÐ°ÐºÑÐ¸Ð¼ ÐÑÐ±Ð¸ÑÐµÐ»ÐµÐ²" 
                ["timestamp_ms"]=> int(1543822921939) 
                ["content"]=> string(333) "Ð²ÑÐµÐ¼ Ð¿ÑÐ¸Ð²ÐµÑ, ÑÑÐ»ÑÑ Ð² ÑÐµÑÐ¸ Ð¸ Ð½Ð°ÑÐµÐ» Ð²ÐºÑÑÐ½Ð¾ÑÑÐ¸ Ð´Ð»Ñ yii2, ÑÐµÐ±ÑÑÐ° ÑÑÑÑÐ¿Ð°ÑÑ Ð½ÑÐ¶Ð½ÑÐµ Ð²Ð¸Ð´Ð¶Ð¸ÑÑ: https://www.2amigos.us/open-source?page=1&per-page=9" ["share"]=> array(1) { ["link"]=> string(52) "https://www.2amigos.us/open-source?page=1&per-page=9" } 
                ["type"]=> string(5) "Share" 
            } 
        } 
        ["title"]=> string(21) "ÐÐÐÐ.tech" 
        [is_still_participant"]=> bool(true) 
        ["thread_type"]=> string(12) "RegularGroup" 
        ["thread_path"]=> string(36) "archived_threads" 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

видимо, как-то так.

```
$result = array_map(function($v){
                return [
                    'sender' => $v['sender_name'],
                    'ts' => $v['timestamp_ms'],
                    'link' => isset($v['share']) ? $v['share']['link'] : null
                   ];
             }, $data['messages']);
```